# Handler callback receiving data accurately on chart

Tags: java, handler

`o.setValue(o.getValue() + message);` this is my problem. If I write there only `o.setValue(message)` its ok. I can see message value on my chart. but when I add historical data to message. I can't receive true value.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        Bundle b = msg.getData();

        int message = b.getInt(Ble_VALUE_MSG_Data);
        o = ds.getOrtoToday(mDeviceAddress);

        if (o == null) {
            o = new Orto();
            dateNow = new Date();
            o.setDate(dateFullFormat.format(dateNow));
            o.setDest(10);
            o.setMac(mDeviceAddress);
            o.setValue(message);
            ds.addOrtoOrUpdate(o);
            reset();
        } else {


            o.setValue(o.getValue() + message );
            ds.addOrtoOrUpdate(o);
            reset();


        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I get it;

mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);